# Why is a nested public class less accessible than it's parent?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, nested-class

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Navigator<T> where T : Navigator.Route
{
    public class Route
    {
    }
}

public class P2PNavigator : Navigator<P2PNavigator.Route>
{
    public class Route : Navigator.Route
    {
    }
}
```

During compilation I receive two errors.

> Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type 'Navigator.Route' is less accessible than Navigator<T>'
>
> Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Navigator.Route' is less accessible than class 'P2PNavigator.Route'

Everything has `public` accessibility.  What am I missing to make this work?  I realise I could ultimately make them all namespace level classes, but I would prefer to have nesting.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the answers, I found the root cause of the problem was my partial classes weren't defined properly.

```
public partial abstract class Navigator<T> where T : Navigator.Route
{
}

partial class Navigator // Different to Navigator<T> and implicitly internal.
{
    public class Route
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a definition for Navigator.Route here.  I see P2PNavigator and Navigator<T>, which is not Navigator

Comment: Per @Moho, it is critical to show that, for instance I get exactly your errors (with good reason) if that class is not public like `class Route { ... }`

Comment: I would consider moving the public nested classes out of the objects.  If you use Code Analysis you'll get [Nested types should not be visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx)

Comment: @JG in SD, thanks!  I'm all for best practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Navigator.Route` is not the same as `Navigator<P2PNavigator.Route>.Route` and should be giving you other errors.

Code that specifies types correctly compiles ok:

```
public abstract class Navigator<T> where T : Navigator<T>.Route
{
    public class Route
    {
    }
}

public class P2PNavigator : Navigator<P2PNavigator.Route>
{
    public class Route : Navigator<P2PNavigator.Route>.Route
    {
    }
}
```

You probably have some non-generic `Navigator` class that makes your sample comile with errors you see.

Comment: should be public abstract class Navigator<T> where T : Navigator<T>.Route
    {
        public class Route
        {
        }
    }

    public class P2PNavigator : Navigator<P2PNavigator.Route>
    {
        public new class Route : Navigator<Route>.Route
        {
        }
    }

Comment: @KeithNicholas, good point on adding `new` to second `Route` class if one wants to compile without warnings. I'd keep code as is since it probably should be fixed differently in real code.